# jQuery sliding menu - .stop()

Tags: jquery

I have this problem. I have sliding menu (3 levels) and when I several quick cross over menu with the mouse it sliding up and down several times. I know that jQuery function .stop() repair this but I dont know how to use it.

I have this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('menu li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.menu2').slideDown().end().find('a.prvy').css('backgroundPosition','bottom center');
        var width = $(this).find('ul.menu2').css("width");
        $(this).find('ul.menu2 li ul.menu3').css("left",width);
        $(this).find('ul.menu2>li').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('ul.menu3')).fadeIn().end().find('div.text').addClass('activ');
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('ul.menu3').fadeOut().end().find('div.text').removeClass('activ');
        });

    }, function() {
        $(this).find('ul.menu2').slideUp(300).end().find('a.prvy').css('backgroundPosition','top center');
    });
});
```

I tries somethink likes:

```
 $('menu li').stop(false,true).hover(function() {
```

OR

```
 $('menu li').stop(true,true).hover(function() {
```

But it doesnt work.

Thank you for your answers and sorry for my English.

Comment: when you get a correct answer please mark it as accept it will benefit to other googlers and the answerer too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call stop within your hover functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('menu li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul.menu2').stop(...
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('ul.menu2').stop(...
    });
});
```

Update based on @tfbox's other comments:

You will want to call `stop` with `true, true` since you are using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.  If you do not want to jump to the end then you can't use these and should instead use `fadeTo`.

Comment: Deleted my post, it's been a long day lol. Surprised I missed that.

Comment: I use stop(true,true) as you say. But nothing happened. http://scooter-racing.eu/neweb/

Comment: Updated my answer.  You need to call stop on the element you are animating.  `$(this).find('ul.menu2')`